# Not able to start new activity on List item click?

Tags: android, android-listview, onitemclicklistener

I am working on application in which I am not able to start new activity on list item click.When I click on List item the app crashes and I could not find the error. The code for the activity is

```
public class CourierActivity extends Activity {
    DBController dbc=new DBController(this);
    Cursor c;
    SimpleCursorAdapter sca;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.courierlist);
        final ListView courierlists=(ListView) findViewById(R.id.courierview);
        dbc.open();
        c=dbc.getcouriername();
        String [] from ={"couriernames"};
        int [] to={R.id.couriertext};
        sca=new SimpleCursorAdapter(this, R.layout.courierlistrow, c, from, to);
        courierlists.setAdapter(sca);
        sca.notifyDataSetChanged();
        c.requery();
        courierlists.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                Intent i=new Intent(CourierActivity.this,ServiceActivity.class);
                i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
                startActivity(i);

            }
        });

    }

}
```

And this is my logcat output:

```
08-24 07:03:54.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1377): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
08-24 07:03:54.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1377): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.datab/com.example.datab.ServiceActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-24 07:03:54.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2180)
08-24 07:03:54.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2230)
08-24 07:03:54.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:141)
08-24 07:03:54.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1234)
08-24 07:03:54.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
08-24 07:03:54.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
08-24 07:03:54.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5041)
08-24 07:03:54.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
08-24 07:03:54.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
08-24 07:03:54.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:793)
08-24 07:03:54.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:560)
08-24 07:03:54.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
08-24 07:03:54.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1377): Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
08-24 07:03:54.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at com.example.datab.ServiceActivity.onCreate(ServiceActivity.java:34)
08-24 07:03:54.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5104)
08-24 07:03:54.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1080)
08-24 07:03:54.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2144)
08-24 07:03:54.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     ... 11 more
```

Comment: show your code for `listview` `onclick` method

Answer (score 1):

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                Intent in1 = new Intent(getBaseContext(), SecondActivity.class);
                    startActivity(in1);

                }
            });
```

Also add permission to manifest file

```
 <activity android:name=".SecondActivity"  />
```

Comment: This doesn't work. In my listview items i show from database.

Answer (score 1):

You can write the code for intent inside listview's onItemClickListener method like shown below, so that irrespective of the listview's position you clicked it will take you to the new activity.

And, also don't forget to declare your new activity in manifest.

```
listview.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

          //@Override
           public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                  int position, long id) {

            Intent ide = new Intent(Activity1.this,Activity2.class);
            ide.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
            startActivity(ide);

           }
 });
```

Comment: Actually I display listview data from database.So that any changes need?

Comment: From where ever you populate your listview, you no need to worry about that..The above mentioned code will itself work.

Answer (score 0):

The error point is

```
    Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    08-24 07:03:54.103: E/AndroidRuntime(1377):     
at com.example.datab.ServiceActivity.onCreate(ServiceActivity.java:34)
```

There is null pointer exception in your `ServiceActivity` `line number 34` check that , you might be using any object which is not initialized 
It should solve your problem